# How to use break statement in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to Javascript. I started with a very basic project in Angular i.e. Form validation. In my case I've to call my custom method, `validationTest()` within itself only once. If I do not put any break condition then there will be too many recursions. I have to stop this. I tried many other solutions:

1. [Break Statement in TypeScript](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/break-statement-in-typescript2/)
2. [TypeScript - Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_loops.htm)

I followed them very carefully, but I'm getting this:

> Module parse failed: Unsyntactic break (84:12)

Here's my code:

```
validationTest() {
    let count =0;
    this.isAnyRangeInvalid = false;
    this.monthpicker.forEach(picker => {
        if (picker.isValidRange === false) {
            this.isAnyRangeInvalid = true;
        }
    });
    count ++;
    if(count===1) {
        break;
    }
    this.validationTest();
}
```

Even VScode editor is also showing a red zig-zag line under the token `break`.
I'm coming from Java and CPP background. Please correct me.

Comment: You mean: `if(count===1) {
            return;
        }`

Comment: `break` is to break out of a `for` or `while` loop or a `case` statement.  If you want the function to finish and return, you use `return`.

Comment: This is not a Typescript issue, your problem is that your code is just not valid Javascript. `break` is for use inside loops, indicating that you want to *break* out of the loop. If you want to end the function if count is 1, then you should use `return`.

Comment: I don't think so this issue is with TypeScript bcz, typescript supports break statement but ideally it is used while iterating over loops. you can use return in conditional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop a function from executing, use `return`. `break` only makes sense in the context of a `for` or `while` loop.

But another problem is that your `validationTest` doesn't have a *persistent* view of the `count` variable - it's completely local, so the test isn't going to work anyway. Consider passing a parameter instead, which will indicate whether the current call is recursive or not:

```
validationTest(lastTry = false) {
    this.isAnyRangeInvalid = false;
    this.monthpicker.forEach(picker => {
        if (picker.isValidRange === false) {
            this.isAnyRangeInvalid = true;
        }
    });
    if (!lastTry) this.validationTest(true);
}
```

Make sure that the initial call of `validationTest` doesn't pass a parameter, or passes `false`.

For a more general solution of limiting yourself to N recursive tries, you can pass around a number instead, eg:

```
validationTest(triesLeft = 3) {
    this.isAnyRangeInvalid = false;
    this.monthpicker.forEach(picker => {
        if (picker.isValidRange === false) {
            this.isAnyRangeInvalid = true;
        }
    });
    if (triesLeft !== 0) this.validationTest(triesLeft - 1);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. All the unit test cases are also passing. I was trying to put my C language tricks that too incorrectly. Thanks a lot. :-)